# Concatenate multiple twig variables in one bracket

Tags: variables, twig

I want to concatenate 3 variables in one bracket, like PHP.

i.e

In PHP:

```
getimagesize($path.$image)
```

We can concatenate variables with dot notation. How can I reproduce this in twig?

`{{ path.key }}` isn't working as intended.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the tilde character `~` to concatenate string and/or variables.

> ~: Converts all operands into strings and concatenates them. {{ "Hello " ~ name ~ "!" }} would return (assuming name is 'John') Hello John!.

Read about it [in the documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#other-operators).